# Extract data from a table with XML column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I've the below sample XML saved in a table called CE_ExtendedElements and column called xmlValue

```
<SIF_ExtendedElements xmlns="">
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="EmergencyNumber">00000000</SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="EmergencyNumber">00000000</SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="Qualifications">
  <Qualification>
    <Qualification>Bsc</Qualification>
    <QualificationWhenHired>True</QualificationWhenHired>
    <Major>Compuetr</Major>
    <GraduationYear>1993</GraduationYear>
    <Institution>Home Univ</Institution>
    <CountryID>1234</CountryID>
  </Qualification>
  <Qualification>
    <Qualification>Bsc</Qualification>
    <QualificationWhenHired>True</QualificationWhenHired>
    <Major>Compuetr</Major>
    <GraduationYear>1993</GraduationYear>
    <Institution>Home Univ</Institution>
    <CountryID>1234</CountryID>
  </Qualification>
</SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="JoinDate">2003-09-15T00:00:00</SIF_ExtendedElement>
</SIF_ExtendedElements>
```

The maximum nodes for any item is 2 only (the user can add 2 EmergencyNumber and 2 Qualifications for each record).

Can somebody help me in reading the above XML using SQL statement to convert the XML nodes as columns? Same as the below table:

EmergencyNumber1 | EmergencyNumber2 | Qualification1 | QualificationWhenHired1 | Major1 | .....| Qualification2 | QualificationWhenHired2 | Major2 | .....

Thanks

Comment: First things first. Create your table. Then post the create table sql code in your question. I'll build your query. So, you have a table called ce_ExtendedElements that possess one column of type xml? That's the first step required to be able to parse it.

Comment: You need to dynamically create columns `EmergencyNumber1`, `EmergencyNumber2`, etc.? Or they are already there in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say, that the structure of your XML seems to be not the best possible...

But you might try it like this:

#### Attention, used a dummy-namespaces and changed the data for better control

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<SIF_ExtendedElements xmlns="http://dummy_uri">
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="EmergencyNumber">11111111</SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="EmergencyNumber">22222222</SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="Qualifications">
    <Qualification>
      <Qualification>Bsc1</Qualification>
      <QualificationWhenHired>True</QualificationWhenHired>
      <Major>Compuetr</Major>
      <GraduationYear>1991</GraduationYear>
      <Institution>Home Univ</Institution>
      <CountryID>1111</CountryID>
    </Qualification>
    <Qualification>
      <Qualification>Bsc2</Qualification>
      <QualificationWhenHired>True</QualificationWhenHired>
      <Major>Compuetr</Major>
      <GraduationYear>1992</GraduationYear>
      <Institution>Home Univ</Institution>
      <CountryID>2222</CountryID>
    </Qualification>
  </SIF_ExtendedElement>
  <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="JoinDate">2003-09-15T00:00:00</SIF_ExtendedElement>
</SIF_ExtendedElements>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://dummy_uri')
SELECT Elmt.value('(SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="EmergencyNumber"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS EmergencyNumber1
      ,Elmt.value('(SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="EmergencyNumber"])[2]','varchar(max)') AS EmergencyNumber2
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/Qualification[1]','varchar(max)') AS Qualification1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/QualificationWhenHired[1]','bit') AS QualificationWhenHired1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/Major[1]','varchar(max)') AS Major1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/GraduationYear[1]','int') AS GraduationYear1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/Institution[1]','varchar(max)') AS Institution1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[1]/CountryID[1]','int') AS CountryID1 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/Qualification[1]','varchar(max)') AS Qualification2
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/QualificationWhenHired[1]','bit') AS QualificationWhenHired2 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/Major[1]','varchar(max)') AS Major2
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/GraduationYear[1]','int') AS GraduationYear2
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/Institution[1]','varchar(max)') AS Institution2 
      ,Qlfct.value('Qualification[2]/CountryID[1]','int') AS CountryID2 
FROM @xml.nodes('/SIF_ExtendedElements') AS A(Elmt)
CROSS APPLY Elmt.nodes('SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="Qualifications"]') AS B(Qlfct)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AbuYazan Glad to read this and thx for the acceptance one tiny hint: Below the other answer you say "thank you" this is very kind of you, but it would be even kinder to vote all good contributions up. This is the SO-way to say thank you... and it is the measure tool of quality... and it is the fuel SO is running with... I just visited your profile and found, that you did not raise one single vote up to now... May I ask you to start to vote whereever something good crosses your path? Happy Coding!

Comment: Actually I was not aware of this:) Will start doing that immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)


SELECT @XML = XMLvalue FROM CE_ExtendedElements


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


SELECT EmergencyNumber1, EmergencyNumber2, Qualification, QualificationWhenHired, Major, Institution, CountryID
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'SIF_ExtendedElements/Qualifications/Qualification')
WITH 
(
  EmergencyNumber1 [varchar](50) '../../@EmergencyNumber1',
  EmergencyNumber2 [varchar](50) '../../@EmergencyNumber2',
  Qualification [varchar](100) '@Qualification',
  QualificationWhenHired [varchar](50) '@QualificationWhenHired',
  Major [varchar](50) '@Major',
  Institution [varchar](50) '@Institution',
  CountryID [varchar](50) '@CountryID'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

This should be pretty close!

Comment: Also.. you'll have to probably change the xml value for emergencynumber to make them distinct. It doesn't appear to be a valid xml format.

Comment: Furthermore, with xml, you can't have them merged within the same line with "dynamics" column names (major 1,2,3 etc). It'll provide you with a single line for all items. If you have two qualification, that person will be represented on two lines.

Comment: `SELECT FROM OPENXML` with the procedure calls to prepare and remove the document is absolutely outdated...

Comment: Yah eh? SQL2005 is a bit old. But it's still supported in SQL Server 2016 (also needed for MCSE 70-462)

Comment: *Still supported* doesn't mean you should use it... There are some rare performance related situations where `FROM OPENXML` is still a good choice (especially if you want to read from the same XML more often), but new solutions should use the much better performing and much easier to handle XML methods with `XPath` and `XQuery` ...

Comment: Great! Thanks! Always nice to hear about new things. I'll look up xpath and xquery for my own benefit =)

Comment: It's Canadian. As for the meaning beneath the saying, you are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110542/discussion-between-wickedfan-and-shnugo).